# Need to replace specific text in CSV file using batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file

I want to replace specific text in CSV file in specific column. I'm able to do that using old post. But that code is not working when my CSV data contains space. I am not batch script expert so I am not able to fix it. I tried many things.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inputCSV=TestCSV.csv
set outputCSV=TestCSV2.csv

(for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (%inputCSV%) DO (
  set column=0
  set "line="
  for %%i in ( %%a ) do ( 
    set /a column+=1
    set value=%%~i
    if !column!==4 (   
      if "!value!"=="TEST" set "value=abc"
    ) 
    set "line=!line!,"!value!"" 
  )
  echo !line:~1!
))>%outputCSV%
```

---

```
ID,Name,Date,Field1,Test Data  Space Check
1010101,Test 1,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,TEST,Test Data  Space Check
2020202,Test 2,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,TEST,Test Data  Space Check
3030303,Test 3,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,TEST,Test Data  Space Check
4040404,Test 4,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,TEST,Test Data  Space Check
5050505,Test 5,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,TEST,Test Data  Space Check
```

---

I ALso tried this but it didn't work.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inputCSV=TestCSV.csv
set outputCSV=TestCSV2.csv
:: tokens=* 
(for /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (%inputCSV%) DO (
  set column=0
  set "line="
  for /f "delims=," %%i in ( %%a ) do ( 
    set /a column+=1
    set value=%%~i
    if !column!==4 (   
      if "!value!"=="TEST" set "value=ABC"
    ) 
    set "line=!line!,"!value!"" 
  )
  echo !line:%%a!
))>%outputCSV%
```

This is how the final output looks
[image: Final Output]

Old post: [Use batch scripting to replace null values with 0 in a specific column in a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103318/use-batch-scripting-to-replace-null-values-with-0-in-a-specific-column-in-a-csv?newreg=7c621bb710cb4a109722ff28e15f9daf)

Comment: Are you still replacing null values in column `4` with `0`? or is the code not related to the task you're now wanting it for? Also you need to expand on where the issue lies with csv data containing a space, because we cannot see it, and you've not attempted to account for that.

Comment: @Compo I am replacing some string with another string. Something like `if "!value!"=="Test" set "value=ABC"`.  I have updated the question with test csv data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your excel image you also seem to have an issue with a BOM (byte order mark) from your used editor.

The old post you reference is different because there all fields are quoted.

To split your csv at the commas use the comma as a delimiter in the for /f (provided there are no commas **inside** the field data).

To exchange a text, use string replacement (what requires to copy to a regular (non for meta) variable inside a code block what in turn requires delayedexpansion).

This batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\22\SO_54312302.cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inputCSV=TestCSV.csv
set outputCSV=TestCSV2.csv

(for /f "tokens=1-4* delims=," %%a IN (%inputCSV%) DO (
  set "col4=%%d"
  set "col4=!col4:foo=bar!"
  Set "col4=!col4:test=abc!"
  echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!col4!,%%e
))>%outputCSV%
```

yields this output:

```
> type TestCSV2.csv
ID,Name,Date,Field1,Test Data  Space Check
1010101,Test 1,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,abc,Test Data  Space Check
2020202,Test 2,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,abc,Test Data  Space Check
3030303,Test 3,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,abc,Test Data  Space Check
4040404,Test 4,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,abc,Test Data  Space Check
5050505,Test 5,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,abc,Test Data  Space Check
```

When importing in Excxel use the comma as delimiter.

Comment: thanks your answer worked for me. Just small thing if I need to replace another value in same column I can add that. Means I need to replace two or more values in the same column?

Comment: To exchange other values, you need additional set commands, I'll insert one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a good CSV tool as Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc)

It's very simple. With

```
mlr.exe --csv put '$Field1=gsub($Field1,"TEST","Foo")' input.csv
```

You have

```
ID,Name,Date,Field1,Test Data  Space Check
1010101,Test 1,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,Foo,Test Data  Space Check
2020202,Test 2,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,Foo,Test Data  Space Check
3030303,Test 3,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,Foo,Test Data  Space Check
4040404,Test 4,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,Foo,Test Data  Space Check
5050505,Test 5,01/27/2001 10:00:00 PM,Foo,Test Data  Space Check
```

It's a great opensource multiplatform utility. Here you have also the win exe https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

You could, I suppose, utilise PowerShell from a batch file.

*Basic Example:*

```bat
@PowerShell -NoP -C "Import-Csv '.\TestCSV.csv'"^
 "|%%{$_.'Field1'=$_.'Field1' -CReplace('^TEST$','ABC');$_}"^
 "|ConvertTo-CSV -N|Out-File '.\TestCSV2.csv' -Fo -En ASCII"
```

*…and to make it a little easier to understand/modify*

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Inp=.\TestCSV.csv"
Set "Out=.\TestCSV2.csv"
Set "Col=Field1"
Set "Old=TEST"
Set "New=ABC"

PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Import-Csv '%Inp%' "^
 "| ForEach-Object {$_.'%Col%'=$_.'%Col%' -CReplace('^%Old%$','%New%'); $_} "^
 "| ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Out-File '%Out%' -Force -Encoding ASCII"
```